# What would happen if I am adding existing entity object to DbContext?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

In my project I am using following code to copy existing record as a new record.

```
  // Copying existing purchase order
  Purchase newPurchase = this.currentPurchase
  // Add copy to DbContext
  this.boManager.Add(newPurchase);
  // Saveing changes and handle exceptions
  CommitChanges();
```

It seems working, but I observed that what happens seems be that it rely on entity frame figure out that when I am adding an existing record, I am actually want adding a new one with essential same data, and will do that for me, but it also could figure out that I am adding a mistakenly adding an existing record and it is better don't do anything since the record is already there.

So my question is:

1. Is my interpretation about internal work of Entity correct?
2. Should I rely on that code to do the copy new function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purchase newPurchase = this.currentPurchase

This only copy the reference to the currentPurchase object rather than create new object. You should use clone() or just create an Purchase object and you can then map all fields from currentPurchase to the new obj and add the new obj to the context.

Comment: Thank you Sza, feel stupid now :D. For solutions you suggested, I think you are talking about the Generic Clone extention method there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178080/linq-to-sql-copy-original-entity-to-new-one-and-save? And map means by reflection right? I am using the Generic Clone method, had to turn lazy loading off to fight against automatic EF proxy but otherwise working well.