# Update a property on objects in a list and add it to another list without editing the original list using LINQ

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I would like to copy objects from one list into another and edit them without altering the original list.

```
Dim myList1 as New List(Of myObject)
myList1.Add(New myObject() With {.foo = 1, .bar = 0, .baz = 0})

Dim myList2 as New List(Of myObject)
myList2.AddRange(myList.Select(Function(x) x.bar = 1))
myList2.AddRange(myList.Select(Function(x) x.baz = 1))
```

Desired `myList2`:

```
{.foo = 1, .bar = 1, .baz = 0}, {.foo = 1, .bar = 0, .baz = 1}
```

Actual `myList2`:

```
{.foo = 1, .bar = 1, .baz = 0}, {.foo = 1, .bar = 1, .baz = 1}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I find it hard to believe that LINQ can't do this natively and that I have to write a custom `.Clone()` extension like [this SO post recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2178383/585552).

Comment: "I find it hard to believe that LINQ can't do this natively": it has nothing to do with Linq; it has to do with how reference types work... Linq does manipulations on collections, cloning objects is completely outside its scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your type is a reference type LINQ will not make a copy of the instance, it will just copy the reference. So both lists contain references to the same instance of `myObject` and that's why you're seeing that kind of output.

You can write your own way to clone the object (e.g. implement `ICloneable`) or change your LINQ query to following:

```
myList2.AddRange(myList.Select(Function(x) new myObject With { .foo = x.foo, .bar = x.bar, .baz = 1 }))
```