# Set old object to new object Linq 2 SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to do an update through LINQ 2 SQL in my asp.net app.

First I have to get the old value from the database, then apply the changes, and then do db.SubmitChanges(); to apply the update.

How can I set the old object to the new object without having to define all the new values?

For example:

How can I do

```
OldUser = NewUser;
```

Instead of:

```
OldUser.FirstName = NewUser.FirstName
OldUser.LastName = NewUser.LastName
OldUser.Phone = NewUser.Phone 
OldUser.Email = NewUser.Email 
OldUser.Gender = NewUser.Gender 
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq to sql, copy original entity to new one and save](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178080/linq-to-sql-copy-original-entity-to-new-one-and-save)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a type: User

`OldUser = new User(NewUser);
db.SubmitChanges()`

create a constructor that does what you described

Comment: Ok - so a constructor has to be written that sets each and every record individually?
There is no default setting (like with an integer or string that overwrites the object)?

Comment: That would create a new user instead of updating one.  This could work if it was a method instead of a constructor.

Comment: My mistake. Surely, when doing some form of SaveOrUpdate(), if the RecordId is the same as an existing one, it would go with the update path?